# Set a TeamCity parameter to a date variable

Tags: teamcity

I have a TeamCity build that passes some arguments to an .exe and runs it daily.  One argument is for a date parameter, currently set to a static date.  It now needs to be dynamic, passing in the current date.

I tried setting the value to %env.BUILD_START_DATE% but this makes all my agents incompatible because of an implicit requirement for that env variable.  I also tried setting the date in the DOS command line script, skipping TC params altogether, but it still ends up with that implicit requirement.

Comment: Powershell has `get-date`.  You could add a powershell script that sets the variables value that way.

Comment: Use some variation of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019954/teamcity-current-date-variable-in-mmdd-format

Comment: If you need current date in you exe then why do you have to pass it from TeamCity? Build start and current date will be just seconds away.

Comment: The exe needs to accept any date.  For my implementation it needs the current date but other implementation need to pass it a static/specific date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top answer here: [TeamCity Current Date variable in MMdd format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019954/teamcity-current-date-variable-in-mmdd-format)
indicated need for a TC plugin, the second answer, however, did not require a plugin and is mostly complete.  How I made it work on a variation of that second answer:

1.) Add a powershell build step to run the following:

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.BUILD_START_DATE' value='$([DateTime]::Now)']"
```

2.) Give env.BUILD_START_DATE a default value in the Environment Variables section.  Without the default value TC thinks having this value is an implicit requirement of a build agent, rendering all of them incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unfamiliar with PowerShell, here is a Bash approach.

You can set a parameter with script and retrieve the value from the next build step.

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.BUILD_START_DATE' value='$(date +%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%M:%%S%%z)']"
```

The doubled `%%` is because TeamCity considers `%` as its own parameter in build script.

The parameter will have ISO8601 format timestamp. For other formats, please see various Bash date format at here; https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-date-format-options-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variable in the config, which should be overridden during runtime.  I don't see env.BUILD_START_DATE in my TC parameters, but I do see system.buildStartTime.  I set it to a dummy value (I use "[Filled Automatically]"), and everything works fine.  Build gets run and system.buildStartTime gets overridden at build time.